# 'match' property not set on props when using MemoryRouter in test

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have been trying to get tests working for react-router v4. I have taken the documented basic [example here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) and written the following test for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Topic } from './App';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('it renders', () => {
  TestRenderer.create(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/topics/props-v-state']} initialIndex={0}>
        <Topic/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});
```

I get the error: **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"** which I interpret as the `match` property not
being set on props of the `Topic` component by `MemoryRouter`. My dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "22",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "6",
  "babel-preset-react": "6",
  "jest": "22",
  "react-test-renderer": "16"
},
```

I guess I could just do `<Topic match={{url: '/topics/props-v-state'}} />` but the [documentation here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing)
seems to imply that this can be done through MemoryRouter.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The `match`, `history` and `location` props are only passed to components rendered by a Route component. Other components that need access to these properties can be wrapped with a call to the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC.

Your example could be written:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Topic } from './App';
import { MemoryRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const RTopic = withRouter(Topic);

test('it renders', () => {
  TestRenderer.create(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/topics/props-v-state']} initialIndex={0}>
        <RTopic/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});
```

As an alternative, your App module could directly export a component that is wrapped by withRouter.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre - that's moved me on. I can now see match,etc being set on props. match.url is still set to "/", however, which makes me think maybe there is something else I need to do?

Comment: `match` is only relevant on routed components (see the doc: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match). Your `Topic` component is not conditionally rendered here. If you need to know what your actual path is, you can use the `location` props (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location).

Answer (score 2):

I believe `<Route component={Topic} />` instead of `<Topic/>` would also work.